# WARN Item with ID={97ADE186-643D-46A9-BAC5-C88077260694} cannot be deleted because it is not found

Tags: indexing

On our CD server i'm seeing a lot of warnings (see below), not quite sure where this is getting invoked from or whats triggering this even though the analytics and tracking is disabled.

Noticed `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Agents.IndexingStateSwitcher` job starts frequently but not entirely sure if its caused by this. ( There's no other error or exception thrown)

```
4652 11:46:41 WARN  Item with ID={ECE6663E-5B9E-44B6-9FE4-80A9EBF2F6E3} cannot be deleted because it is not found
4652 11:46:41 WARN  Item with ID={59616A63-2A1B-4545-B857-ABF989565CA4} cannot be deleted because it is not found
4652 11:46:41 WARN  Item with ID={BD14153A-1B25-47ED-B613-99DF1255CBF2} cannot be deleted because it is not found
4652 11:46:41 WARN  Item with ID={FC6978BB-5BA0-426B-BFBD-6F9F87878A00} cannot be deleted because it is not found
5828 11:46:44 WARN  Item with ID={102B1A38-B8F3-40F5-9040-2B089E96F0BD} cannot be deleted because it is not found
5828 11:46:44 WARN  Item with ID={9D0B7468-F3B0-4018-A361-A98099AB3C75} cannot be deleted because it is not found
5828 11:46:44 WARN  Item with ID={EF6ACECB-029A-4A3F-857B-AE5E095AE542} cannot be deleted because it is not found
5828 11:46:48 WARN  Item with ID={7FE3536F-3D18-48D0-BBA4-8B82F21E0636} cannot be deleted because it is not found
5828 11:46:48 WARN  Item with ID={18119430-6FAF-41A1-8F6B-F62C75B2AE0E} cannot be deleted because it is not found
5828 11:46:48 WARN  Item with ID={74343F57-5264-468A-99C2-A8D4874F01AE} cannot be deleted because it is not found
5828 11:46:48 WARN  Item with ID={D65BCA42-544C-4EE5-83EA-BF4C32C03EB7} cannot be deleted because it is not found
5828 11:46:48 WARN  Item with ID={2A9826F6-48A6-450E-826D-3F0AB4D09BFB} cannot be deleted because it is not found
```

Sitecore Verson 9.3

Comment: I think this is related to items that are still in your queues but no longer in the index - Sitecore tries to remove them and can't. Try to clear the event queue and/or rebuild the indexes - that should get rid of the warnings.

Comment: Are you using Glass mapper?

Answer (score 2):

Just assuming that you might be using Glass Mapper.. if so, you are probably running into an issue in Glass for Sitecore 9..2+ as described here: https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/402

Although the logs are probably annoying, you can ignore them as they are perfectly safe. Apparently Sitecore changed added some logging to the item delete method causing all those logs - but there is nothing wrong with your setup.

If you want to get rid of the messages, you could filter them - check this Q/A for ideas on that: [Filter standard Sitecore log messages into separate logs](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/8937/237)